# How to navigate DOM from Wicket

Tags: wicket

I wonder if it is possible to modify the HTML code of the parent of a wicket component in the Java code to modify its attribute without making it a component in wicket. For example, I would like to add active to the li tag from Java.

```
<li>
   <a wicket:id="home" href="#">
     <i class="icon-home"></i>
     <span>Home</span>
   </a>                     
</li>
```

and the say add an Attribute to that parent without referencing it in code as a component.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, it would be completely against the modular nature of Wicket. (Not to mention the fact that pages are actually rendered as a stream, there's no DOM tree built.)

Components in Wicket shouldn't depend on what's outside of them. What if you want to change the logic of active/inactive controls? Or, in a more likely scenario, you just want to change the markup. Or if you just want to unit test your component without any surrounding markup.

Wicket was designed to avoid these "spooky actions at a distance", to create components that are genuinely testable on their own.

You need a component that encapsulates the entire list, which keeps track of which of its items is active (via its model). It might seem at first like a lot of work but when you look at the result, you'll realise how much easier it is to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your position on this, I think it will be possible to build a DOM tree however, I believe the memory footprint would be higher if wicket has to keep track of all HTML tags before rendering a page.

Comment: Just to make it clear, this is not my position, this is what Wicket was designed to do. You should either follow the philosophy of Wicket or if you don't like it, choose a different framework, but trying to shoehorn something alien into a framework is rarely a good idea. And if you're worrying about memory footprint **before** you even get your solution to work, that's definitely not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript. In this example I overrided the renderHead() of the link, but it can also be done with a Behavior.

```
public class TestPage extends WebPage {

    public TestPage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);

        add(new AjaxLink<Void>("link") {
            boolean active = false;
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                active = !active;
                target.add(this);
            }
            @Override
            public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
                super.renderHead(response);
                String addOrRemove = (active) ? ".addClass('active')" : ".removeClass('active')";
                response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("$('#" + getMarkupId() + "').parent('li')" + addOrRemove + ";"));
            }
        });
    }
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  li.active {background-color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a wicket:id="link">TOGGLE</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Yes, it will couple the code to the markup, but this is not always a problem. If you feel you are copying and pasting this code over and over, consider creating a proper component :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I would have preferred a case where wicket allows me to get the parent markup container in Java code instead to add an AttributeModifier.

Comment: In theory you could try to manipulate it through the markup stream, but it would probably be VERY complicated, if possible at all. Just add the container :)